Network unclaimed Linux Mint 21.3
this is my first time building a computer and I've run into a problem, even though the motherboard I'm using a B550 Aorus Elite AX v2 is supossed to have on board wifi, I can't connect to the wifi without an adapter and even then can only see 2.4g wifi.
I've checked the same adapter on different machines and it can see 5g, so I don't think it's a problem with the adapter.
When I run sudo lshw -class network I see.
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 74:56:3c:cb:a7:fd
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-106-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:35 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc600000-fc60ffff memory:fc610000-fc613fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc5fffff



I'm 100% sure it has something to do with the network being unclaimed, but I don't know how to solve that.
And when I run inxi -Fxz i see
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-106-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0
    Desktop: Cinnamon 6.0.4 Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: B550 AORUS ELITE AX V2 v: x.x
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: FD
    date: 06/08/2023
CPU:
  Info: 12-core model: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3
    rev: 2 cache: L1: 768 KiB L2: 6 MiB L3: 64 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2651 high: 3594 min/max: 2200/3700 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 2191 2: 2196 3: 2191 4: 2191 5: 2193 6: 2194 7: 2871 8: 2871
    9: 2865 10: 2871 11: 3592 12: 3593 13: 2196 14: 2192 15: 2191 16: 2190
    17: 2192 18: 2193 19: 2872 20: 2862 21: 2869 22: 2870 23: 3594 24: 3591
    bogomips: 177264
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] vendor: PNY driver: nvidia
    v: 535.171.04 bus-ID: 06:00.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.171.04 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA102 High Definition Audio vendor: PNY
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 06:00.1
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: Gigabyte
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 08:00.4
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-106-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE vendor: Gigabyte driver: r8169 v: kernel
    port: e000 bus-ID: 04:00.0
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek driver: N/A port: d000 bus-ID: 05:00.0
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-5:3
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 14.4 GiB (0.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WD BLACK SN770 2TB
    size: 1.82 TiB temp: 45.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 1.79 TiB used: 14.39 GiB (0.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 35.0 C mobo: 34.0 C gpu: nvidia temp: 50 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0%
Info:
  Processes: 436 Uptime: 46m Memory: 31.26 GiB used: 2.46 GiB (7.9%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Packages: 2261 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13



Your USB dongle not seeing 5GHz network is unrelated to the internal one being unclaimed. Please [edit] the question and post the correct identification of said device. It should be listed with lspci.
